# Does EF not using the same old concept of creating large query that leads to degrade performance?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I know this could be a stupid question, but a beginner I must ask this question to experts to clear my doubt.
When we use Entity Framework to query data from database by joining multiple tables it creates a sql query and this query is then fired to database to fetch records.

> "We know that if we execute large query from .net code it will
>   increase network traffic and performance will be down. So instead of
>   writing large query we create and execute stored procedure and that
>   significantly increases the performance."

My question is - does EF not using the same old concept of creating large query that leads to degrade performance.

Experts please clear my doubts. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether EF magically gets data without sending bytes across a network? What?

Comment: To be clear: LINQ to Entities generates SQL, just like any other SQL.

Comment: I am asking - We use stored procedure in order to avoid network traffic by not using old "large queries". But by using EF are we not going to old age by again using again "large queries"

Comment: Are you on a 2800 baud modem or something?

Comment: By "large queries" do you mean a long SQL statement, or are you talking about a query that returns too much data and eats up bandwidth? I'm not aware of any prescribed use of stored procedures because they are shorter in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to popular myth, stored procedure are not any faster than a regular query.  There are some slight, *possible* direct performance improvements when using stored procedures ( execution plan caching, precompiltion ) but with a modern caching environment and newer query optimizers and performance analysis engines, the benefits are small at best.  Combine this with the fact that these potential optimization were already just a small part of the query results generation process, the most time-intensive part  being the actual collection, seeking, sorting, merging, etc. of data, these stored procedure advantages are downright irrelevant.

Now, one other point. There is absolutely no way, ever, that by creating 500 bytes for the text of a query versus 50 bytes for the name of a stored procedure that you are going to have any effect on a 100 M b / s link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473299/benefits-of-stored-procedures-and-sql-server-2008-performance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973918.aspx.

Comment: ..... "However, stored procedures can still provide performance benefits where they can be used to reduce network traffic. You only have to send the EXECUTE stored_proc_name statement over the wire instead of a whole T-SQL routine, which can be pretty extensive for complex operations." **ridiculous, even in 2004**  "A well-designed stored procedure can reduce many round trips between the client and the server to a single call.". **perhaps, but this is such a complex topic about the data-island engineering of your application it inclusion here is essentially just advertising**

Comment: Thanks Smith, this doubt was in my mind since long but now its clear :). Thanks again...

Comment: Cheers, see the references in comments for more ammo during testy meetings.

Comment: Strictly speaking, EF's SQL provider *does* use stored procedures for parameterized queries - it calls "sp_executesql" over RPC.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not sure this has any effect on performance especially regarding my macro level performance analysis answer though.